# Why is python Celery trying to use SSLv3 authentication when trying to connect to RabbitMQ over TLS?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, tls1.2, sslv3

I installed the latest version of Erlang and RabbitMQ from source:

- Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.4.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:1]
- RabbitMQ 3.7.17
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 3.6.7
- celery 4.3.0

My /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config

```
[
 {ssl, [{versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1']}]},
 {rabbit,
  [
    {tcp_listeners, [{"127.0.0.1", 5672}]},
    {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
    {ssl_options, [{cacertfile, "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt"},
                   {certfile, "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/server.crt"},
                   {keyfile, "/usr/local/share/private/server.key"},
                   {versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1']},
                   {verify, verify_peer},
                   {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true}
                  ]},
    {auth_mechanisms, ['PLAIN', 'AMQPLAIN', 'EXTERNAL']}

  ]
 }
].
```

I have verified that those `.crt` and `.key` are actually in `.pem` format. And here is my `celeryconfig.py`:

```
import ssl
broker_url="amqps://USER:PASSWORD@rabbit-endpoint.com:5671//"
result_backend="I am using postgresql"
include=["my_tasks.py"]
task_acks_late=True
worker_prefetch_multiplier=1
worker_max_tasks_per_child=25
timezone="UTC"
broker_use_ssl={'keyfile': 'beep.key', 'certfile': 'beep.crt', 'ca_certs': 'boop.crt', 'cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED}
```

Whenever I start up my celery workers. I get this message:

```
consumer: Cannot connect to amqps://USER:**@rabbit-endpoint.com:5671//: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:847).
```

I read that the latest version of Erlang/RabbitMQ should not be accepting SSLv3 due to some vulernabilities, so I am not sure why Celery is trying to authenticate with SSLv3.